# React: Error : Objects are not valid as a react child?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

This hook for sending API calls works perfectly fine. It has been working fine for last 6 months.

I have no clue why it is failing for a single route.
All the errors returned from the API have the **same structure** :

```
[{ message: "Invalid username" }, { message: "Invalid password" }]
```

> **Error**

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: [object Object]). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

> **Hook**

```js
export const useRequest = ({ url, method, body, onSuccess }) => {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(null);
  const makeRequest = async (e) => {
    try {
      setErrors(null);
      const { data } = await axios[method](url, { ...body });
      if (onSuccess) {
        // will invoke callback function that is passed
        onSuccess(data);
      }
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      if (err && err.response?.data && err.response?.data.errors) {

        // figuring out what is going wrong!
        err.response?.data.errors
         .map((each) => console.log(typeof each.message)); // returns string

        setErrors(
          // <== SHOWS ERROR HERE !!!!! WHY??!!
          <ul className="errors-list">
            {err.response?.data.errors.map((each, index) => (
              <li key={index}>{each.message}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        );
      }
    }
  };
  return { makeRequest, errors };
};
```

This is the first time it is showing error, it has never in last 6 months behaved like this.
Please help!

Comment: Can you put this in a sandbox?

Comment: Take a look at your network panel in devTools ... Seems like `each.message` is at some moment an object which leads to the error ...

Comment: You can try using .toString() on each.message to see if that temporarily fixes you problem. Might be something causing the unordered list to close and and then you would have multiple objects.

Comment: I did, it didn't help. I also console.logged the each.message, it is a string only.

Comment: hmm try commenting out the setErrors(...) to verify that is the problem area.

Comment: ```err.response?.data.errors.map((each) => console.log(typeof each.message));``` returns *string* only :"(